# Ember.js CLI Build Broccoli Funnel not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am trying to use the Broccoli Funnel package to pull a complete directory into my assets folder in an Ember CLI build. Please find my ember-cli-build.js file below:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    //
  });

  var extraAssets = new Funnel('vendor/images/frames/artist/64', {
    destDir: '/assets/images'
  });

  app.toTree(extraAssets);

  return app.toTree();
};
```

The directory "vendor/images/frames/artist/64" only contains .png image files and I would like to have them all available after the build at "assets/images/64/". After a build process, there is no images folder created in my assets directory.

Can you help advise where I have gone wrong? Are there any debugging tools to show what Broccoli Funnel is trying to add to the build and where those files are being distributed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.ToTree` accepts an array of transformed nodes (**trees** in [broccoli 1.x.x](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli/blob/master/docs/broccoli-1-0-plugin-api.md#cosmetic-changes)).

Also, you have to return the node transformed by your `app.toTree` call.

So instead of,

```
...

app.toTree(extraAssets);

return app.toTree();
```

You would do,

```
return app.toTree([extraAssets])
```

---

Like [Lux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871354/2108366) suggests, using `broccoli-merge-trees` is encouraged.

```
var EmberApp   = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'),
    Funnel     = require('broccoli-funnel'),
    MergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    //
  }),
  nodes = [];

  nodes.push(new Funnel('vendor/images/frames/artist/64', {
      destDir: '/assets/images'
  }));

  nodes.push(app.toTree());

  return new MergeTrees(nodes);
};
```

---

### Debugging Broccoli Trees/Nodes

For debugging your `broccoli` plugin output, use [broccoli-stew](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-stew). Here's a quick sample to list out the files that are present just after the Funnel step.

```
var EmberApp   = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'),
    Funnel     = require('broccoli-funnel'),
    MergeTrees = requre('broccoli-merge-trees'),
    log        = require('broccoli-stew').log;

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    //
  }),
  loggedNode,
  nodes = [];

  funnelOutput = new Funnel('vendor/images/frames/artist/64', {
      destDir: '/assets/images'
  }));

  nodes.push(log(funnelOutput))

  nodes.push(app.toTree());

  return new MergeTrees(nodes);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [MergeTrees](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-merge-trees):

```
return new BroccoliMergeTrees([app.toTree(), extraAssets]);
```

instead of

```
app.toTree(extraAssets);

return app.toTree();
```